# Problem with the switch conditional statement in the email template?

Tags: email-template, administration

```
{CASE(Account.AccountSource, "ABC-Website", "Diese haben wir über unsere Website erlangt","Sportsponsoring" "Diese haben wir über ein soziales Netzwerk erlangt" "")}
```

I don't understand what's wrong here since when I test it, I get the whole chunk of the conditional statement. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a comma in fallback and exclamation sign:

```
{!CASE(Account.AccountSource, 
    "ABC-Website", "Diese haben wir über unsere Website erlangt", 
    "Dateneinkauf", "Diese haben wir durch einen Einkauf von Daten erlangt", 
    "Empfehlung", "Diese haben wir mittels Empfehlung erlangt", 
    "Eventsponsoring", "Diese haben wir über das Sponsoring eines Events erlangt", 
    "Kaltakquise", "Diese haben wir durch eine eigene Recherche erlangt", 
    "Kooperationspartner", "Diese haben wir über einen unserer Kooperationspartner erlangt", 
    "Messe", "Diese haben wir über unseren Kontakt auf einer Messe erlangt", 
    "Netzwerk", "Diese haben wir durch unser gemeinsames Netzwerk erlangt", 
    "Plattform", "Diese haben wir durch eine genutzte Plattform erlangt", 
    "Sportsponsoring", "Diese haben wir über das Sponsoring des Sports erlangt", 
    "Vermittler", "Diese haben wir durch einen Vermittler erlangt", 
    "Fachveranstaltung", "Diese haben wir über eine Fachveranstaltung erlangt", 
    "Wirtschaftsprüfer", "Diese haben wir über einen Wirtschaftsprüfer erlangt", 
    "Berater", "Diese haben wir über einen Berater erlangt", 
    "Kundenkontaktaufnahme", "Diese haben wir durch Ihre Kontaktaufnahme erlangt", 
    "Soziale Netzwerke", "Diese haben wir über ein soziales Netzwerk erlangt", 
    "")}
```

Comment: I now see nothing :/

Comment: Could be because `Account.AccountSource` does not matches any condition and the fallback you had defined is empty `""` at the end of `Case` method

Comment: Fixed, Thank you. I was missing another picklist field .

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the critical `!` which makes this an expression for the template renderer to evaluate:

```
{! CASE
```

rather than

```
{CASE
```